# Multiple screen sessions with different layouts: is it possible?

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

The title pretty much says it all, but here is a short additional example:

**What I'd like:**

- Multiple screen windows
- Multiple "contexts": for example a "resources" context, a "compiling" context, etc.
- Each context can have it's own subset of open windows which are divided by split-screens

At this moment, it seems only possible to create multiple screen sessions to achieve this.

**Is it possible to create *one screen instance* that provides the above functionality?**

If not, is it possible to switch between active screen instances just as you would switch between the windows by using `^A "`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window splits seem to be per-login, but doing so seems to somewhat mangle your buffer sizes if you use multi-attach (screen -x).  You might be able to get something similar to what you want using multi-attach, but your question doesn't include exactly what you want, so hopefully the pointer to the -x option will help.

You can run screen under screen, though.  To save your sanity I'd suggest changing the 'context switcher' screen instance's hotkey to something other than ^A.

It also sounds like you might be interested in something like [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/) or [StumpWM](http://www.nongnu.org/stumpwm/) if you've got a linux desktop.